# Scenic dependencies on Windows?

Tags: windows, elixir, scenic

### Background

I have been playing around with [Scenic](https://hexdocs.pm/scenic/welcome.html) to make a desktop app across multiple environments. While the [`Install dependencies`](https://hexdocs.pm/scenic/install_dependencies.html#content) for Ubuntu are outdated and don;t work for the latest LTS (v20) I was still able to figure out the packages and install it on Ubuntu Linux.

However ... there is nothing for Windows.

### Questions

1. Does Scenic even work on Windows?
2. If so, what are the dependencies? What need I to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Unfortunately, Scenic does not run on Windows, nor can it support it.
At the time of writing of this post, I am also unaware of any plans to make it work on a Windows system.

The confirmation came from an official collaborator from the Scenic project:

https://github.com/boydm/scenic/issues/206